# Iterative SQL query using loops?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with many rows and many numbered columns, similar to this one:

| "name"1 | "name"2 | "name"3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | ... |

I need to preform a dynamic query on all the columns from "name" 1 to "name" n, while n is a number that I receive from somewhere else.

Is there a way to implement a loop into the query that will preform this task for me? Or do I need to write an external script that will build the query string? I'm using SQL server

*Edit* I'm using SQL 19, not 05 as the a tag suggested,
and I cant change the structure of the table.

Comment: SQL Server 2005? *Really*? You are *long* overdue a upgrade.

Comment: What are you expected results here? Why not fix your design and normalise it?

Comment: My original dataset is a table that contains data from several types of automatic processes, each type with its own number of stages.
Each row is a stage, I've pivoted the data around the stage number and now i need to be able to query differently for each type of process, hence the different columns for each query

Comment: But why do you have multiple name columns? This violates basic normalisation forms. Each name should be its own row.

Comment: the names are the stage numbers. 
im trying to go from
| stage num | time | batch |
|-------------|------|--------|

to
| batch | stage 1 time | stage 2 time|
|-------:|---------------|--------------|

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Larnu, these stage times should be in rows, not columns. But since you're stuck with a bad design:

```
DECLARE @NumberOfColumns int = 30;

DECLARE @Columns nvarchar(max) = N'', 
        @sql     nvarchar(max);

SELECT @Columns = 
STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(CONCAT(N'stage ', n, ' time')), 
  N',' + char(13) + char(10))
FROM 
(
  SELECT TOP (@NumberOfColumns) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID)
  FROM sys.all_columns 
  ORDER BY [object_id]
) AS x;

SELECT @sql = N'SELECT batch, 
' + @Columns + N' FROM dbo.tablename;';

SELECT @sql;
-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Output:

```
SELECT batch, 
[stage 1 time],
[stage 2 time],
[stage 3 time],
[stage 4 time],
[stage 5 time],
[stage 6 time],
[stage 7 time],
[stage 8 time],
[stage 9 time],
[stage 10 time],
[stage 11 time],
[stage 12 time],
[stage 13 time],
[stage 14 time],
[stage 15 time],
[stage 16 time],
[stage 17 time],
[stage 18 time],
[stage 19 time],
[stage 20 time],
[stage 21 time],
[stage 22 time],
[stage 23 time],
[stage 24 time],
[stage 25 time],
[stage 26 time],
[stage 27 time],
[stage 28 time],
[stage 29 time],
[stage 30 time] FROM dbo.tablename;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f92833590556584e0a28ca9dfcbe8782)

A slightly more clever way relies on the actual metadata for the table in question:

```
DECLARE @NumberOfColumns int = 30;

DECLARE @Columns nvarchar(max), 
        @sql     nvarchar(max);

;WITH cols AS 
(
  SELECT i = TRY_CONVERT(int, PARSENAME(REPLACE(name,' ','.'),2)),
       name = QUOTENAME(name)
  FROM sys.columns 
  WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.SomeTable')
    AND name LIKE N'stage% [0-9]% time'
)
SELECT @Columns = STRING_AGG(name, N',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY i)
FROM cols WHERE i <= @NumberOfColumns;

SET @sql = N'SELECT batch, ' + @Columns + N' FROM dbo.SomeTable;';

SELECT @sql;
-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql;
```

Yes, you can do this with a loop, but it's a really bad idea to set this kind of example:

```
DECLARE @NumberOfColumns int = 30;

DECLARE @i int = 1, @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT batch';

WHILE @i <= @NumberOfColumns
BEGIN
  SET @sql += N',' + char(13) + char(10)
    + QUOTENAME(CONCAT('stage ', @i, ' time'));
  SET @i += 1;
END

SET @sql += N' FROM dbo.SomeTable;';

SELECT @sql;
-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f44643240d31df1f91794bd912aa8d4c)

Comment: it looks good, but I think that its couple of levels above me.
I thought about something like using a loop to write the query string and than execute it.
Is that a thing?

Comment: @ubs Sure, but writing loops in T-SQL is almost always the worst way to accomplish something and - even though in this case this really is still a loop - it sets a bad example. How do you get to levels above you if you don't embrace and learn new things at other levels?